# Linked List replaces the front node instead of popping onto back

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm working on creating a doubly linked list. I seem to be having issues with the `pushBack` function (supposed to add a node to the end of the list). Somehow it just replaces the first node and points to itself as both the previous and next node. When I go to print the list, it just goes on forever because the next node isn't NULL (because as I said, it's pointing to itself for some reason). Posted below is the entire program. I think I might be having an issue with scope or possible am using the pointers incorrectly.

```
#include <iostream>

class Node {
public:
  Node();
  Node(int *val, Node *nx = NULL, Node *prev = NULL) {
    value = val; next = nx; previous = prev;
  }

  void setPrev(Node* prev) { previous = prev; }
  void setNext(Node* nx) { next = nx; }
  void setVal(int* x) { value = x; }
  Node* getPrev() { return previous; }
  Node* getNext() { return next; }
  int* getVal() { return value; }

private:
  int* value;
  Node *next;
  Node *previous;
};

class LinkedList {
 public:
  LinkedList() : front(NULL), back(NULL) {}

  bool empty() { return front == NULL; }
  void pushBack(Node *nd) {
    if (back == NULL) {
      front = nd;
      back = nd;
    }
    else {
      back->setNext(nd);
      nd->setPrev(back);
      back = nd;
    }
    std::cout << "Front: " << *front->getVal() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Back: " << *back->getVal() << std::endl;
  }
  Node* topFront() { return front; }
  void printFront() {
    int *x = front->getVal();
    std::cout << *x << std::endl;
  }

  void print() {
    if (empty()) {
      std::cout << "List is empty" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
      std::cout << "Print list" << std::endl;

      Node *x = front;
      int count = 1;

      // First just print the first element, then the rest
      int *y = front->getVal();
      std::cout << count << ": ";
      std::cout << *y << std::endl;

      x = x->getNext();

      while (x != NULL) {
        std::cout << count << ": ";
        int *z = x->getVal(); std::cout << *z << std::endl;

        x = x->getNext();
      }
    }
  }
 private:
  Node* front;
  Node* back;
};

int main() {
  LinkedList ll;
  char input;
  char const *menu = {"Options:\n\n" \
                      "0. Quit\n" \
                      "1. Print linked-list\n" \
                      "2. pushBack -- add to the end of the LinkedList\n"};

  while (input != '0') {
    std::cout << menu << std::endl;
    std::cout << ":";

    std::cin >> input;

    if (input == '1') {
      ll.print();
    }
    else if (input == '2') {
      std::cout << "Value: ";
      static int init;
      std::cin >> init;
      static Node x(&init);
      ll.pushBack(&x);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Below is the input that I used. I printed some values to try to debug the program. You'll notice, I just tried putting the nodes with values 1, 2, 3 and 4 into the list

```
Options:

0. Quit
1. Print linked-list
2. pushBack -- add to the end of the LinkedList

:2
Value: 1
Front: 1
Back: 1
Node Prev: 0
Node Next: 0
Options:

0. Quit
1. Print linked-list
2. pushBack -- add to the end of the LinkedList

:2
Value: 2
Front: 2
Back: 2
Node Prev: 0x602300
Node Next: 0x602300
Options:

0. Quit
1. Print linked-list
2. pushBack -- add to the end of the LinkedList

:2
Value: 3
Front: 3
Back: 3
Node Prev: 0x602300
Node Next: 0x602300
Options:

0. Quit
1. Print linked-list
2. pushBack -- add to the end of the LinkedList

:2
Value: 4
Front: 4
Back: 4
Node Prev: 0x602300
Node Next: 0x602300
Options:

0. Quit
1. Print linked-list
2. pushBack -- add to the end of the LinkedList

:0
```

Comment: BTW, you can place the code for class methods outside of the class.  This reduces the amount of code the compiler has to parse when including the header files.

Comment: Please read about the MCVE in the site guidelines. In particular, it shouldn't be necessary to guess what you input in order to reproduce the issue. Replace that with hardcoded values. That also helps you, because it's in the last step where the actual corruption of your data structure happens. BTW: Do you know what `static` does?

Comment: I recommend using a debugger **and** drawing the linked list as you step through your program.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews yes, I was aware. Is there a big difference? I just didn't feel like making a header file

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt will do. I'll head over and read that. I'll update the question to include my inputs

Comment: @ThomasMatthews great, thanks. I will look into that!

Comment: Those getters and setters in your `Node` class are quite unnecessary. Instead, I would make `LinkedList` and `Node` friends.

Comment: @MikeBorkland why is that?

Comment: Concerning extracting a header, generally yes. However, if you wanted a linked list, you would use `std::list<>`. You are doing that for learning though (I guess), so it makes sense to keep it all in one file.

Comment: Because you can access the members of `Node` directly. Example: if you pass `Node *p` to a function, you can get access to its `next` pointer with `p->next`.

Comment: @MikeBorkland my understanding was that it is a good habit to not access members directly and to use public functions to access them outside of the class

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt yes, this is purely for learning

Comment: @David Are you sure you want `value` to be an `int*`? Why is it not an `int`?

Comment: @David In general, yes, that is good advice. For example, you wouldn't want the user to be able to access the `prev` and `next` pointers. However, there is no reason why the `LinkedList` class should not be able to access the `next` and `prev` pointers of a `Node` in the list. If you declare `friend class Node;` in your `LinkedList` class, then `LinkedList` will be able to access the private variables of `Node`.

Comment: @super it easily could be. I just chose that for the slight savings. Also mostly for practice with using pointers

Comment: Public vs private depends on what you're doing with it. In the case of `Node` you have a public setter function that does absolutely nothing to protect the object from someone setting an invalid value and a public getter that hands the value out to all who ask.  The only difference between this and a public variable is a few extra lines of code and a place to hang a debugger breakpoint.

Comment: @MikeBorkland ok yeah that makes sense. Didn't think of it that way. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @David I don't think you are saving anything. You are just loosing by using a pointer there.

Comment: @super fair enough

Comment: Slight savings is actually a loss. The pointer may well be larger and more expensive to copy than an int. Plus using a pointer makes it harder on the CPU to cache the value. With an `int`, when you load a `Node`, you also load the `int`. With a pointer you likely have to dive back into slower storage looking for the pointed-to `int`.

Comment: Unrelated: In the `print` function I think you're missing a `count++` in the `while` loop.

Comment: Once you are done solving this yourself, just use [std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) or (usually better) [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of good tips here, but none so far will solve the fundamental problem: you need to allocate the Node instances on the heap instead of the stack.

To make this easier, I'm going to suggest you store the ints by value instead of a pointer. Change all the places you use int* to just plain 'int'.

Then change the code to push a node on the back to this:

```
else if (input == '2') {
  std::cout << "Value: ";
  int init;
  std::cin >> init;
  Node *x = new Node(init);
  ll.pushBack(x);
}
```

I've tested this with your code and it worked for me.

When you do something like this:

```
    else if (input == '2') {
  std::cout << "Value: ";
  int init;
  std::cin >> init;
  Node x(init);
  ll.pushBack(&x);
}
```

You're allocating a Node on the stack, which means as soon as you exit the "else" block the Node 'x' is destroyed and the pointer you added to your list is no longer valid.  You need to allocate Node on the heap with the new operator.  That will keep the Node alive and in memory until you delete it later.

Speaking of delete -- once you get this part working, you'll want to write a destructor that iterates over all the nodes in your list and deletes them.  But for now, I'd focus on getting your other operations correct.

Comment: Minor niggle: `Node` is `static` in the asker's source. It's not on the stack.

Comment: Another recommendation worth adding: Have `pushBack` take an `int` parameter and create the `Node` inside `pushBack` with the passed-in `int`. The user of the Linked List shouldn't have to deal with nodes. That's the linked list's job.

Comment: Value is a int pointer.

Comment: @user4581301 the suggestion to have the pushBack() take the int value is an excellent design suggestion.

Comment: @AbhijitPritam true, but the general consensus is that using a pointer to an `int` is a bad idea. It's slower, probably larger, and adds additional memory management issues.

Comment: @Jason, that answer makes sense to me. I guess I need to do a little more reading up on this topic (which is why I'm doing some practice and getting some great help from you all). I was also under the impression that a pointer is automatically deleted when it leaves scope. I guess I don't understand that very well either. Either way, thanks for the input

Comment: @user4581301 that makes perfect sense to me. I will be implementing that

Answer (score -1):

As you are using a static variable in below code all your node will have first value you entered.

```
static int init;
std::cin >> init;
static Node x(&init);
```

Correct it like below and try again

```
int *init = new int;
std::cin >> *init;
Node *x = New Node(init);
```

Your pushBack method look good for me. Just make above change and try.

Comment: `empty` is telling you if the list is empty of not, it's not removing/deleting anything.

Comment: @user4581301, modified my answer. Thanks  for your valuable suggestions :-)